# How should the hyper parameters be defined for the other algorithms defined for sklearn_crfsuite.CRF

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, perceptron

In the [example](http://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#hyperparameter-optimization) given for [sklearn_crfsuite](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sklearn_crfsuite.CRF), the parameter space that needs to be passed to a cross_validating class like [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) is defined as below.

```
params_space = {
    'c1': scipy.stats.expon(scale=0.5),
    'c2': scipy.stats.expon(scale=0.05),
}
```

In the example the algorithm that is shown is "lbfgs". Other supported algorithms in sklearn_crfsuite are "l2sgd", "ap", "pa", "arow". How should the variable `params_space` be defined in those cases?

Answer (score 4):

`C1` and `C2` are coefficients for L1 and L2 regularization, respectively. You can use the same definition of `params_space` regardless of the optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the documentation which parameters apply to which algorithm. Depending on the algorithm you can optimize different ones, such as c1 and c2 but also epsilon or gamma.
https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html